# Ruby 2.3.1 has a bug in `Module#alias` and `Module#alias_method`?

Tags: ruby, alias

Consider the following code:

```
module M
  def original ; puts __callee__ ; end
  alias_method :aliased, :original
end
class A
  include M
end

A.new.original
#⇒ original
A.new.aliased
#⇒ aliased
```

The above code runs perfectly fine in Ruby 2.1 and returns the actual method name, as it is supposed to be done by [`Kernel#__callee__`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-__callee__).

Surprisingly enough, the code above *does not work as expected* in Ruby 2.3.1:

```
A.new.original
#⇒ original
A.new.aliased
#⇒ original
```

Is this a desired behaviour I failed to find in release notes, or is it a bug in MRI for 2.3? The same happens for `alias`.

PS I have created an issue https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12761

Comment: I deleted my answer because I misunderstood the question. 

I can reproduce the behavior. Works on 2.2, does not work on 2.3.1

Comment: And it only happens with included module, not with class.

Comment: “it only happens with included module, not with class”—yes, I provided a minimum viable example.

Comment: This was only intended as further hint for others who want to investigate.

Comment: This question belongs on https://bugs.ruby-lang.org ;-)

Comment: @Stefan indeed, I am filling a bug, I just wanted to make sure I am not mistaken / missing smth.